# Using xtable to generate printable outputs from R

Tags: r, format, output, xtable

I'm trying to learn how to use xtable to create tables that I can use to present my research results. I've cut and pasted the suggested code from a tutorial but don't get the results in the format that is expected.

Here is the code:

```
library(xtable)
data("tli")
options(xtable.floating = FALSE)
options(xtable.timestamp = "")
xtable(tli[1:10, ])
```

The tutorial suggests that I should now get a table that looks like this:

[image]

However all I see in my console in RStudio is the following:

```
> xtable(tli[1:10, ])
% latex table generated in R 3.3.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% 
\begin{tabular}{rrlllr}
  \hline
 & grade & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & tlimth \\ 
  \hline
1 &   6 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  43 \\ 
  2 &   7 & M & NO & BLACK &  88 \\ 
  3 &   5 & F & YES & HISPANIC &  34 \\ 
  4 &   3 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  65 \\ 
  5 &   8 & M & YES & WHITE &  75 \\ 
  6 &   5 & M & NO & BLACK &  74 \\ 
  7 &   8 & F & YES & HISPANIC &  72 \\ 
  8 &   4 & M & YES & BLACK &  79 \\ 
  9 &   6 & M & NO & WHITE &  88 \\ 
  10 &   7 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  87 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This output is for Latex. If you are constructing your presentation in Beamer, then this is the output format that you want. You might also be interested in an Rmarkdown presentation, which should be able to convert this text into the above format (though I haven't tried). `xtable` also allows for the construction of HTML tables, which will probably work for MS Office or LibreOffice with a bit of conversion tools like pandoc.

Comment: Thanks @lmo - I'm not familiar with Beamer, Latex or Rmarkdown (I'm a relative beginner here). In that case, should I perhaps be looking at a different package (instead of xtable)? I'm wanting an output that I can paste into MS Word.

Comment: You might play around with the output as HTML and see if it will import it properly. As an alternative, there are pieces of software (outside of R) that will convert HTML or Latex tables to rtf, that you can easily import into word. If you want to do this in R, I'd recommend getting familiar with the Rmarkdown package. You can actually get it  to  produce .docx files that contain your text, tables, and figures. The package is produced by the people at rstudio and has seemless integration with that IDE. Produce the table there and copy and paste if you want. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Comment: If you definitely want to export directly to Word, consider the `ReporteRs` or `officer` packages.

Answer (score 0):

Use **results="asis"** chunk option, something like this:

`<<message=F, warning=F, echo = F, results = "asis">>=`

The **asis** option write text output as-is, i.e., write the raw text results directly into the output document without any markups.

See more at https://yihui.org/knitr/options/